# Draw Something turn out of synch

Tags: draw-something

Ok, I am in a weird state in one of my games.  It seems that my device forgot about one of my drawings even though it was sent to my partner.  So now her guesses show up as guesses for the next drawing.  I drew a music box, and she guessed it, but her guess showed up in the queue for my next drawing, of a dogsled.  So when I click the game, it shows her guessing  'musicbo' for dogsled, and getting it wrong and resetting our streak, even though it presumably already told her she got musicbox right.

I tried killing the app, and resetting the device, but no luck.  I have no idea what will happen when her dogsled guess comes through.  Maybe it will synch up.

Anyone seen anything like this?

**ETA** let it continue after showing her getting dogsled wrong, streak counter jumped back up to where it should be if she got it right?  Sent another drawing, now have two outstanding...

**EATA** So my dogsled drawing never made it to her; it disappeared into the æther.  From her point of view, it was all normal, like Timothy Roy said below, and we're back in sync now.  Glad I didn't spend more time on that particular drawing, since it went nowhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same thing happened to me once, my friend didn't see anything bto him it was just the normal game and everything looked the same.
I then accepted his 'wrong' guess and reset our streak to 1, but to him it was still on 60 or something. When I drew another one, he guessed it right and sent one back to me, my draw something synchronized to his and we were back on 62.

So for me everything worked out in the end, I hope it'll be the same for you.